# Aligning stepper divs inside a container using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a list of header icons in a Stepper inside a container and I am trying to get them to be responsive to the page size changes but it is not working. I have tried to change the place of the container in different div but it did not work.

I am using Bootstrap5

Here is the current output:
[image]

I am trying to get the numbers inside the container
here is the template:

```
    <div class="container flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-0 py-5">
      <div class="mb-5 p-4 bg-white shadow-sm">
        <h1 class="text-center">Plan</h1>
        <div id="stepper1" class="bs-stepper">
          <div class="bs-stepper-header" role="tablist">
            <!-- General Information -->
            <div class="step active" data-target="#test-l-1">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="step-trigger"
                role="tab"
                id="stepper1trigger1"
                aria-controls="test-l-1"
                aria-selected="true"
              >
                <span class="bs-stepper-circle">1</span>
<!--                <span class="bs-stepper-label">General Information</span>-->
              </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Summary -->
            <div class="step" data-target="#test-l-2">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="step-trigger"
                role="tab"
                id="stepper1trigger2"
                aria-controls="test-l-2"
                aria-selected="false"
                
              >
                <span class="bs-stepper-circle">2</span>
<!--                <span class="bs-stepper-label">Summary</span>-->
              </button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: We need the version of bootstrap and a "working" sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `col` class inside the `div` with a `row` class, for each `button`. It automatically adjusts the width for each button as per the width of the screen. Using `col` class, each `div` with `button` will occupy equal space. In our case since there are 10 `button` elements, with each occupying 10% of the whole width.

You can do it like this:
HTML:

```
<div class="container flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-0 py-5">
  <div class="mb-5 p-4 bg-white shadow-sm">
    <h1 class="text-center">Plan</h1>
    <div id="stepper1" class="bs-stepper">
      <div class="row mt-5 bs-stepper-header" role="tablist">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" data-target="#test-l-1">
          <button type="button" class="step-trigger" role="tab" id="stepper1trigger1" aria-controls="test-l-1" aria-selected="true">
            <span class="bs-stepper-circle">1</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>4</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>5</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>6</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>7</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>8</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>9</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button>10</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can add CSS as well:

```
button {
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

You can through the official documentation here for more information about the Bootstrap grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/

Demo sample: https://codepen.io/Hitesh_Vadher/pen/xxrdYYb